# Cant find elements on popup, site doesnt seem to be using frames using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am clicking on a element that brings up a popup element, then I want to scrape data from this popup element. But I am not able to find the data or close the popup once I open it.

Looking at the element hierarchy, the popup doesn't seem to be in a different frame, but all my searching suggested that's what the problem is, so I tried below code

When I try to switch frames by element I am getting the same unable to locate element and the html data doesnt seem to show a frame related to this popup so I dont know any attributes of the frame to switch to it (I selected all frames and none of them highlighted the popup)

Here is the [webpage]

Clicking on "view details" under the picture shows the popup. How do I select elements on that popup?

```
data = []
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')
e.click() 
e =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[12]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/button')  ## Shows unable to locate element error
driver.switch_to.frame(e)
    for x in range (1,5):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[13]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[{x}]')
    data.append(element.text)  ## Doesnt have the text inside the list
    e.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are not in an `iframe`. So no need to switch to frame. The details appear in a pop-up.

Instead of Absolute xpaths opt for Relative xpaths. [Link to refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Try like below and confirm:

```
# Imports required for Explicit wait:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://koa.com/campgrounds/austin-east/reserve/step2/?res=kI2O68dJS8X6si949wGzFa68NxYqwyCBul7NzF70cO3rQJLWCoDqp38g67l9SA4BcZqoRAxVFUdFtWBLcjbhl55toq-KCG20N36F-ytOHhr3EKHiJ3_qxDvkUMId1flJiRSh-9X6BDSw3EJ_IVCTNjo0ax44UscxXmfNXAVc8WybZ2xp6tu6H9lvR_igbYAXMf2t2dyN_NM-8JDDtJEe1ofkmQmsl1QJPJsZqfNq-cMnDD2mTdNCJxsfUQwEUYrUY6QEsdj3bbLMWqSTRW5bSzEoVNjVNc_dbH4R11-nnZU0tt1uvWNZZH-3OmrZA7Of9BI2W-GO6r9fk2sa0l1AaiCX7yclG2kXAQgxwTTMOfqI6OgYtKDRvEAgHW71w2LycESK3xVuxTP8C_4OwhFEQBg-GYcq-juoe5qeZNBhiBJsWJxqqxpcPBJ4RgeL7l-emnlG9DHqFk-R3LRDnAi2RBXsr9UWmcVwa3vtlXLLHPcJp07uBDPKz4d-Mm2nKPcjlQVQhaN9ooT5Ccvr5LergYRv4XRMI-u6z0gDYMpZUwLSFvQt3wUEXmQyM0PaazwX1fKjUVF9oKnU8yH5BGpy87uR3_QxfE7UP864PWqdaDg6ni3o7qOLnhZGJ-K6Z0oVu9f48BKRPWWX8-pvHRhe7Is6XnxD1_XVWxjAfXeWAxD8R0URqU6v8JvCgKZXJvwP0vjsXLeXtSsEEd2VFyrGk5UHhHuG1cc7YFGTXJBDMPW7E88LI7pkbsecM-Va5X4IrtoHLppMBOeihBj3Cxz9nHLF5X6fkIMRE7BWKh8TQxRTyNhvdNg-zlMAep2boMwQmBbFpyCH8VN_UxroErjaAixJsEdJyphoYPuIkyHOHfvxREsu5A5IR8aowrQMv1Kc04_bMU-BacYCTCAB8jeRv-I3CtuqetXls4DzC49crLDFyewmwIUdUkkWJS79ml_L3vh82vqjJfHnYs5GHYmqdGLlFPBD19hIjcrAcuOTNXFH5et8ShMfMaa1TRSJCTqeDmonbdH2Uv-_u1RAu_SMHDik2N2NCfEi4E-GvN6vw_kvce_yrLyzeVRCseHo0JmgWxpc4C9nwcLsxa7qN16Q6Gh9aa8RP3Od80tDN8SOOLeVStjcKopJU91ui1rSIdv4pncKWImnwOm7xBG2srVefDb7twP--WYZWeX5PyumDLw9-Nb_QN-LpET3ELxsF0eY6GmFYLFWdt38Aosc4hNFzDFQEkZ5KDnbLdvfMeKqXKDGdV9e5OaaynLyQNmvp4ZlLEVdD3LUraSw_TB-JClxIiw9AIYdhn1vlmilk2CsDIbyfF4n2WsxoVs0k0_RsiAcqaL6jEx31_shLwpGidHXgVUYrNaQ3URMf2Y_KUqB9RPIh0e8_aGoFxbthoxKQmyLMRtLutwvwmqQXx5sCEAfwQ2")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Options available on the page
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='reserve-container']//div[@id='site-types']")

# Get details of the 1st option.
viewdetails = options[0].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'reserve-sitetype-main-row')]//a")
viewdetails.click()

# Get the heading
heading = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='fancybox-stage']//h3")))
print(heading.text)

# Get the details under the heading
details = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='fancybox-stage']//h3//parent::div//following-sibling::div//li")

for detail in details:
    print(detail.get_attribute("innerText"))

# Close the pop-up window
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fancybox-stage']//button[contains(@class,'wts-details-close')]").click()
```

```
AUSTIN EAST KOA HOLIDAY
6029 Blue Bluff Road Austin, TX 78724
Email: austineast@koa.com
Reserve: 512-732-2812
Info: 800-562-8743
```

Comment: Thanks! thats worked for me I knew I had to switch to relative xpaths at some point but I didnt think using abs would break my code.